# How do I disable a Wordpress embedded YouTube video's title and logo?

Tags: wordpress

I have a YouTube video embedded in my wordpress blog. How do I disable the title and also perhaps the YouTube button.

Essentially I want to prevent the user for clicking through to YouTube from my blog.

This is the code. I have tried adding variables but when I save it just deletes the extra variables:

```
<a href="http://tidyurl.com/exkn0z" target="_blank"><iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/MzLxLKLErCM?feature=player_detailpage" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe></a>
```

Comment: You can't. If you remove the title, the logo will show up in the bottom right. If you remove the logo from the bottom right, the title will show up. See working demo options: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo. If you don't want branding, don't use YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Youtube embed options, you can easily hide the title bar and change some other things too.

Or just add `&showinfo=0` to the end of your video url.

To access your video's embed options, go the the video page on Youtube, select the share button > select the Embed tab > select the Show More button. You should then see all options.

An example with your video that you can paste in to Wordpress:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MzLxLKLErCM?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However, Wordpress now has a built in facility to turn any Youtube URL in to an `[embed]`. The advantage of Wordpress' function is that the video will be scaled to fit your page provided that the theme has `$content_width` set.

Unfortunately I have not yet found a way to remove the title bar when using Wordpress' built in function, so might be better to go with Youtube's emded code.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding `&showinfo=0` within the quotations doesn't work, neither dies `?showinfo=0`

CSS also doesn't seem to be able to touch it.

What I found out is that the issue is with YouTube, not with WordPress.

Currently, as of 2021, there is no solution for removing just the title from embedded YouTube video.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer, I shared that the examples don't work, I wrote what I tried and I explained that there is no solution so that ppl at least don't waste time trying something that doesn't work.